# OpenMRS and FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, openmrs

I have successfully deployed a localhost instance of OpenMRS using the downloaded war file and reference implementation from Download – OpenMRS.org (I’m using downloads from the 2.12 Advanced Installation and the 2.4.3 war file and the modules from the “Download Reference Application” link.

I’ve included the fhir2-1.2.2.omod file in my deployment (apache-tomcat-8.5.85\webapps\openmrs\WEB-INF\bundledModules) but I’m not seeing how to access OpenMRS using FHIR (the only url tomcat shows for the deployment is the /openmrs url as would be expected).

Is there a separate war file or application that needs to be deployed to access OpenMRS using FHIR?

How do I install this functionality (or is there a url that exists under the /openmrs url that gives access to the FHIR functionality)?

[image]

Comment: FYI please see [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Aside from that: there's no specific programming question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the URL for making FHIR API calls to your OpenMRS instance. That would be {host}/ws/fhir2/{release}/{resource}. The OpenMRS [FHIR wiki](https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/projects/FHIR+101%3A+OpenMRS+Strategy%2C+Tools%2C+FHIR+API%2C+and+Help) and [IG](https://fhir.openmrs.org/index.html) should have the info you need on specific available operations.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers (they're not valid answers). At best, this should be a comment.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I would disagree that this is a link-only answer. The OP asked how to access OpenMRS using FHIR; the second sentence of the answer provides the information. The links are simply supplementary to provide more information and direction.

Comment: Thanks @Ashavan.  I found the info I was looking for: The FHIR API is installed as part of the Reference Implementation deployment.  The URL is http://localhost:8080/openmrs/ws/fhir2/R4/ (http://localhost:8080/openmrs/ws/fhir2/R4/Patient for patients)